# How to aggregate hourly data and plot

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate

I have hourly data with quantities. I would like to aggregate the quantities by hour and plot the result. I enclose the code that I've used. The result that I get is a blank plot and no dates on the x axis. I took some sample data from the internet and saved it as a csv file to practice on. A portion of the data is below:

```
date    quantity
11/02/2011 14:30    123.53
11/02/2011 15:00    123.78
11/02/2011 15:30    124.24
11/02/2011 16:00    124.2
11/02/2011 16:30    124.07
11/02/2011 17:00    123.91
11/02/2011 17:30    123.44
11/02/2011 18:00    123.0616
11/02/2011 18:30    123.06
11/02/2011 19:00    123.13
11/02/2011 19:30    123.745
11/02/2011 20:00    123.96
11/02/2011 20:30    123.99
11/02/2011 21:00    123.99
11/03/2011 14:30    124.3
11/03/2011 15:00    124.38
11/03/2011 15:30    124.67
11/03/2011 16:00    125.19
11/03/2011 16:30    124.9
11/03/2011 17:00    125.27
11/03/2011 17:30    125.5
11/03/2011 18:00    125.58
11/03/2011 18:30    125.91
11/03/2011 19:00    125.8
11/03/2011 19:30    125.83
11/03/2011 20:00    126.215
11/03/2011 20:30    126.25
```

The code that I have used is:

```
groupdf<- read.csv
groupdf$date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(groupdf$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT"))
groupdf$quantity <- as.numeric(levels (groupdf$quantity)) [groupdf$quantity]
groupdfres <- aggregate(groupdf$quantity, 
                    by= list (format(groupdf$date, "%Y-%m-%d %H")), sum)
names (groupdfres) <- c ("date", "count")
groupdfres
plot (groupdfres$date, groupdfres$count, type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Count",
xlim = as.POSIXct(c("2011-01-11 00:00:00", "2011-10-11 23:59:00")))
```

Comment: Try removing the xlim parameter from your plot statement.  xlim is plotting from Jan 1 to Oct 11th.

Comment: Are you able to see values in your data.frame, once you've done the aggregation?